# Get N results for each group without using join

Tags: sql

can I solve this without using join? there are so many data in this table, I want to do it more efficiently.
one of my idea is get **ID** list by using **group_concat** subquery, but it doesn't work well with **IN** clause.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (group_concat subquery)
```

May I get your advice?

```
data
    ID SERVER_ID ...
    --------------------
    1  1  ...
    2  1
    3  1
    4  2
    5  2
    6  2
    7  3
    8  3
    9  3
    10 3
    ...



expected result with limit 2 per each group: 
    ID SERVER_ID ...
    --------------------
    1  1  ...
    2  1
    4  2
    5  2
    7  3
    8  3
```

Comment: which SQL engine are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following using `row_number`, this solution will work for postgreSQL, MySQL 8.0, Oracle and SQL Server.

```
select
    id,
    server_id
from
(
    select
        id,
        server_id,
        row_number() over (partition by server_id order by id) as rnk
    from yourTable
) val
where rnk <= 2
```

Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cbs8qYM75FdxxhZqRoFk9u/0).

```
| id  | server_id |
| --- | --------- |
| 1   | 1         |
| 2   | 1         |
| 4   | 2         |
| 5   | 2         |
| 7   | 3         |
| 8   | 3         |
```